# How to list only odd numbers from text file?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with 2 columns in linux
1st column has the the IP addres
2nd column has the port number

I want list only the odd port numbers with IP addresses

Comment: Sorry, I can't decode your question - can you rephrase please? (maybe give some example too)

Comment: i have a file with name abcd.txt, it has two columns
1st column has the ipaddres and second column has the port numbers
how can list the odd port numbers from this file

Comment: @RamadeviPalagani, avoid confusing and guessing - post a testable input fragment

Answer (score 2):

Below `awk` one liner will get you the result with just one command:

```
awk '$2%2!=0 {print $0}'  file.txt
```

Since you need to display the odd port numbers with their respective IP address, just divide the column 2 number by 2; if the result is not equal to zero, then print the line.

Comment: You don't need to include `$0` as an argument to `print`; that's the default argument.  `awk '$2%2!=0 {print}' file.txt` works just as well.  But in actual fact, `print` is already the default *action* when a condition is true.  So all you need is `awk '$2%2!=0' file.txt`.

Comment: Even no need comparison condition `awk '$2%2' infile` is just enough

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is tab-delimited (tsv)

```
cut -f 2 abcd.txt | egrep '[13579]$'
```

should do the trick.

If you are working with different delimiters or even fixed-width see `man cut` (specifically, the `-d` and `-c` options)

Bonus: add `| uniq` to remove duplicates

---

**edit:** omit the `cut` part if you do not want to remove IP addresses: `egrep '[13579]$' abcd.txt`

---

**edit:** add some explaination

`cut` is an utility that operates line per line and allows to select what parts of the line you want it to output.

You can specify this by character position with the `-c` option (useful with fixed-length fields) or by field with the `-f`(if your data is field-separated).

If you use `-f` the field delimiter is assumed to be the  character, or you can specify a different one with `-d`.

```
echo -e 'abcdefghij\nabcdefghij' # two lines
echo -e 'abcdefghij\nabcdefghij' | cut -c 2-4,7 # selects characters from position 2 to 4 and 7

echo -e 'aa,bb,cc,dd\nAA,BB,CC,DD' # space-delimited fields
echo -e 'aa,bb,cc,dd\nAA,BB,CC,DD' | cut -d , -f 3 # prints only the 3rd field
```

`egrep` (which is the same as `grep -e`) selects lines that match the given *regular expression*. The expression `[13579]$` means *having an odd digit at the end of the line*, so `egrep` only shows line that end in odd digits.

Regular expressions are super-nifty and useful when manipulating text, and so you'll find them in many command-line utilities, text editors and programming languages - they may appear cryptic at first but one really doesn't need to be an expert for most tasks and if you read a bit on the topic (and experiment!), you'll very quickly get the gist of it.

---

**edit:** replaced `(1|3|5|7|9)$` with `[13579]$` as per @HaukeLaging suggestion

Comment: Have fun! :) Also, if you don't understand _why_ that works, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Could you please explain that

Comment: I need one more help Giorgiga

Comment: `grep '[13579]$` makes more sense to me.

Comment: @HaukeLaging agreed: shorter is better! :-) editing

Comment: It is not so much about being shorter but about being simpler. You do not even need `egrep` for that.

Comment: I want to remove the duplicates in that command output

Comment: For Example see this screenshot

Comment: @HaukeLaging As for the regex itself, I concur that yours is clearer/less-boilerplate-y/better. As for plain old `grep`... in general I find that a regex that works with `grep` is "less simple" than the equivalent in extended syntax: contrary to a somewhat widespread belief in the unix community, "ancient" is not synonymous with "simple" :-)

Comment: @RamadeviPalagani add `| sort | uniq` at the end of the line (the pipe character `|` means "take the output of the previous program and give it as input to the next one" - combining simple steps for complex results is possibly the core of unix philosophy) --- Note: I'm not sure the `sort` is actually needed

Comment: In general I would not argue for using a `grep` expression instead of an `egrep` expression. But in this case both `grep` and `egrep` can execute the same expression (with the same result...) and that is an argument for the expression and for using `grep`.

Comment: as i have 2 columns i did the same which you have suggested now i got the file with odd port numbers with corresponding IP-address's but IP-address's  are repeated, now i want the unique IP-address's with corresponding port numbers. can you suggest me

Comment: @RamadeviPalagani Such changes to the question belong in the question part, not in a comment; you may point at the edit in a comment. You still haven't changed the question as you have been told to.

Comment: @HaukeLaging easy, bro :-) it's Hauke's first question - let's be nice especially to newcomers! (also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users )