# Print a string if the last character is odd

Tags: text-processing, string

I have a list of hostnames in a file and want to separate them based on the last character. Write the host name to a file if the last character is odd number. How can I do this in one liner?

Example:

```
abc123
abc124
abc348
abc435
```

Desired output:

```
abc123
abc435
```

Comment: Are those hexadecimal numbers? Are `123bbb`, `234ddd`, `345fff` also to be considered _odd_? How about 123BBB...?

Comment: similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418394/72456

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short **`awk`** command:

```
awk '/[13579]$/' file > hostnames_odd.txt
```

- `[13579]` - character class representing the list of allowed digits (odd numbers)
- `$` - the end of the string/line

---

Result:

```
$ cat hostnames_odd.txt 
abc123
abc435
```

---

Or the same with **`grep`**:

```
grep '[13579]$' file  > hostnames_odd.txt
```

---

In case if there could possibly be a whitespace(s) at the end of some line(s) change the crucial pattern to the following: `[13579][[:space:]]*$`

Comment: Why that print within awk? `awk '/[13579]$/' file > hostnames_odd.txt` seems more concise.

Comment: @fedorqui, yes, we know that. For such simple case it would be enough (updated). But, in other case - the former is more scalable in case if we wanted to distribute lines on different files on some conditions like `awk '/[13579]$/{ print > "hostnames_odd.txt" }/[02468]$/{ print > "hostnames_even.txt" }' file`

Comment: Why present the `awk` first? This is literally what `grep` was created for.

Comment: In order of overkill, probably grep first, then sed, then awk, then Perl @Kevin

Answer (score 4):

A tricky trick here: just [set the field separator to an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31135446/1983854), so that every single character is a field. This way, you just have to check if `$NF` is even or odd:

```
$ awk -F "" '$NF % 2' file
abc123
abc435
```

With other data:

```
$ echo "23
... 24
... 25" | awk -F "" '$NF % 2'
23
25
```

Comment: (with [`awk` implementations that support that non-POSIX extension](/q/417105) (many), `awk -v FS=` would be a bit more portable)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oh thanks! Why is `awk -v FS=` more portable? What other implementations may we _also_ get that wouldn't work with `-F ""`?

Comment: Note , `FS` - `If
the value is the null string (""), then each character in the record becomes a
separate field. (This behavior is a gawk extension. POSIX awk does not specify
the behavior when FS is the null string. Nonetheless, some other versions of
awk also treat "" specially.)`

Comment: See the link I provided.

Answer (score 2):

This will print out the lines read in if the last character mod 2 is not zero.

`perl -wlne 'print $_ if ((substr $_, -1) % 2)' /path/to/file`